# Extract substrings in a string using regex if the prefix matches one from the list

Tags: regex, powershell

The prefixes are  Dog, Cat, Bird, horse and they end with numbers.

The output should only be Dog1234, Cat4567, Bird2342344, Horse898087, Dog2345, Bird2340988

```
$text = 'I Dog1234 need Cat4567 do Bird2342344 extract Horse898087 the  Dog2345 strings that contain the a set of prefixes using regex Bird2340988'

$mymatchedStrings = $text | Select-String -Pattern '.*([Dog|Cat|Bird|Horse]\d+).*' -AllMatches

$mymatchedStrings.Matches[1]
```

Comment: Note that `[Dog|Cat|Bird|Horse]` won't do what you want, because the `[...]` creates a _character set_ that matches any one of its characters in the input, e.g., `'o' -match '[Dog|Cat|Bird|Horse]'` is `$true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Select-String '\b(?:Dog|Cat|Bird|Horse)\d+\b' -input $text -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.matches.value}
```

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:Dog|Cat|Bird|Horse)` - a non-capturing group matching one of the listed alternative words
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - word boundary.

Notes:

- `.*(...).*` patterns match the entire line (or string depending on the context and flags) and thus should not be used in cases when you expect to match multiple substrings in a longer text (as it is the case here)
- `[Dog|Cat|Bird|Horse]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you need a [grouping  construct](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to match alternative multicharacter substrings
- `-AllMatches` returns all matched occurrences, not just the first one
- `Foreach {$_.matches.value}` returns the match text only, not the whole match data info.

Comment: You answer the question so fast that I cannot give you your points yet.  Stand by for your points. LOL.  Thank you so much.